# VIM: How to autocomplete in a CSS file with tag ids and class names declared in HTML file

Tags: css, vim

I'm trying VIM for HTML, CSS and JavaScript editting. I've installed a number of plugins and configured VIM so that it allows me to autocoplete standart HTML/CSS code. And now I want to autocomplete my CSS code with tag ids and class names placed in HTML files just like in Apatana. For example:

I have `1.html` file with the following lines:

```
<div id="my_id"> </div>
<div class="my_class"> </div>
```

And I have `1.css` file with:

```
#my_id{border-style:dotted}
.my_class{border-style:solid}
```

When I'm edditing a CSS file and pressing `<c-x><c-o>` right after `#`, I want VIM to suggest me tag ids from the `1.html` file. The same for tag class names. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-x><C-o>` is for language-specific keywords such as `<table>` in an HTML file or `background-color` in a CSS file, the right shortcuts for word completion are `<C-n>` and `<C-p>`.

Supposing your HTML and CSS files are loaded in two buffers (the HTML can be hidden or visible in a split), you are supposed to type a couple of characters of the id or class name and hit `<C-n>` for a list of possible completions.

Type `:help ins-completion` for more info.

I use [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) which provides realtime completion but there are other options.

Answer (score 5):

What I found helpful was adding the following line to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType css,scss setlocal iskeyword+=-,?,!
```

which helps me autocompleting ids and classes with various special characters.

Comment: I would use `setlocal` here instead of `set` to make it apply only to the buffers of filetype css and scss.